# Styling Address Tag as a Table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having a weird problem. I'm trying to style the `<address>` tag as a table-cell, but browser (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) insists to display it as a block!

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Address Test</title>
<style  type="text/css">

form {display:table;}
p {display:table-row;}
label,a,input,output,address,a {display:table-cell;border:1pt solid silver;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<p>
    <label>Tel:</label>
    <a href="tel:+12345">+12345</a>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Fax:</label>
    <a href="tel:+12345">+12345</a>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <address>bla bla bla</address>
</p>
<p>
    <label>E-Mail:</label>
    <a href="mailto:john@smith.com">john@smith.com</a>
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

... and here's the output:

http://richstyle.org/contact.html

Any help please?

Comment: Why don’t you use a `table` element for this tabular data? Your code uses `label` against the specifications: a `label` element specifies a label for a control (form field), not just any element.

Comment: `<label>` elements label *form controls*, not arbitrary bits of data. You seem to be using them as headings (`<h?>`).

Comment: This is your problem: [No p element in scope but a p end tag seen](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frichstyle.org%2Fcontact.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (as explained by James' answer)

Answer (score 3):

`address` elements cannot be contained within `p` elements. Chrome and Firefox render the markup as:

```html
<p>
    <label></label>
</p>
<address></address>
```

As the [HTML specification suggests](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), dividers would be more appropriate over paragraph tags.

```html
<div>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <address>bla bla bla</address>
</div>
```

```css
div {display:table-row;}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, I used to think that <address> is just like <time>: could be block or inline.
However, I think <address> should be as flexible as <time>.